# Excursion Noise EEG Signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have been doing noise removal from EEG Signal. There are different type of noises present in an EEG signal. I came across with 'Excursion' noise. I search the internet but I cannot find what kind of noise is that. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it denotes the noise caused by the potential shift of the electrodes. Here is a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.499.304&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to that topic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Knipser

Answer (score 0):

Example:

If a student is learning, a distraction in the sustained attention will be termed as Excursion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).